# How does Meteor.js decide the order in which components are rendered?

Tags: meteor, rendering, meteor-blaze

I have the following code in Meteor.js written by someone else

```
<div>
 <div> {{> yield region='tickets'}} </div>
 <div> {{> yield region='ticketView'}} </div>
 <div> {{> yield region='analytics'}} </div>
</div>
```

It works fine but I have an issue with the order in which those components are rendered. When that page is opened, the 'analytics' clearly loads/renders first, then once that is done the rest of it renders. I would like it to load/render in the order that the components are called.

Attaching template files to take a look at

region='tickets' ====> ticketsList (This should always load first)

region='ticketView' ====> ticket_view

region='analytics' ====> analytics

```html
<template name="ticketsList">
  <div id="tickets-list" class="tickets-list">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn btn-primary {{unresolvedActive}}" id="unresolved">
          Unresolved
          <span class="label label-pill label-danger label-as-badge">{{ unresolvedTicketsCount }}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn btn-primary {{resolvedActive}}" id="resolved">
          Resolved
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{> broadcast}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 12px;">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="create-shift-report" style="
            background-color: #278006;
            border-color: #278006;
            border-radius: 25px;
          ">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"
            style="background-color: #278006; color: white"></span>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5" style="float:right">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="create-ticket" style="
            float: right !important;
            background-color: #56cf1b;
            border-color: #56cf1b;
            border-radius: 25px;
          ">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"
            style="background-color: #56cf1b; color: white"></span>
          Create Ticket
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-sm">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0px">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." class="searchInput" id="searchQuery" name="search" />
          <button type="submit" class="searchButton search-button">
            {{#if isSearch}}
            <i class="fa fa-times clearbutton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{/if}}
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{#if isSearch}}
    <div class="row m-t-sm">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <i>
            <h4>Search Results</h4>
          </i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <div class="row m-t-sm">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <span style="font-style: italic;">Filter by department: </span>
          <select class="ticket-department-filter" id="departmentFilter">
            <option>All</option>
            {{#each tags}}
              <option value={{this.id}}>{{this.name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-sm">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <span style="font-style: italic;">Filter by source: </span>
          <select class="ticket-department-filter" id="sourceFilter">
            <option>All</option>
            {{#each sourceFilter}}
              <option>{{this}}</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickets scrollbar m-t-sm">
      {{#if tickets.length}} {{#each tickets}} {{> ticketItem}} {{/each}} {{#if
      showLoading}}
      {{> LoadingNew }}
      {{else}} {{#if noMore}}
      <div class="alert alert-warning m-t-sm" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px">
        No more tickets available!
      </div>
      {{else}}
      <div class="m-t-sm" style="text-align: center">
        <button id="show-more" class="btn btn-primary"
          style="width: 100px; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4">
          Show More
        </button>
      </div>
      {{/if}} {{/if}} {{else}} {{#if showLoading}} {{> LoadingNew }} {{else}}
      <hr />
      <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px">
        <i>No outstanding tickets</i>
      </h2>
      <hr />
      {{/if}} {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>

  {{> shiftReportModal}}

  <div id="new-ticket-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #83ccff">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            &times;
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff">
            Create a New Ticket
          </h4>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="create-ticket-form">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="source">* Source</label></div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="call" value="call" />
                  Call
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="inPerson" value="in-person" />
                  In-Person
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="email" value="email" />
                  Email
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="dnd" value="dnd" />
                  DND
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="shift-report" value="shift-report" />
                  Shift Report
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="soft-check-in" value="soft-check-in" />
                  Soft check-in
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="amenity" value="amenity" />
                  Amenity
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="request" value="request" />
                  Request
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="source" id="repair" value="repair" />
                  Repair
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="guestName">Guest Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestName" name="guestName" />
              </div>
              <label for="autoFill">OR Auto-Fill &nbsp; </label>
              <select id="autoFill" name="autofill">
                <option value="-1">Select Guest</option>
                {{#each pastGuests}}
                <option value="{{ @index }}">
                  {{ receiverName }} ({{ roomNumber }})
                </option>
                {{/each}}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="roomNumber">* Room #</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="roomNumber" name="roomNumber" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="reservationNumber">Reservation #</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reservationNumber" name="reservationNumber" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="email">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="phoneNumber">Phone #</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3" for="notes">* Notes:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" required id="notes" name="notes" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<template name="ticketView">
  <div>
    {{> ticketItemView}}
  </div>
  <div id="tickets-list" class="tickets-list ">
    <div class="btn-group  btn-group-justified">
      {{#if oleryTabs}}
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn1 email-btn {{resolvedActive}} {{#if noEmail}}simptip-position-top{{/if}}"
          id="respondTab" style="background: #41e1eb;">
          Respond
        </button>
      </div>
      {{else}}
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn1 email-btn {{resolvedActive}} {{#if noEmail}}simptip-position-top{{/if}}"
          id="emailtab" disabled="{{noEmail}}"
          data-tooltip="{{#if noEmail}}In-app communication unavailable for Custom Ticket{{/if}}">
          Email
          {{#unless noEmail}}<label class="counts">({{emailcount}})</label>{{/unless}}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn1 sms-btn {{resolvedActive}}  {{#if noPhone}}simptip-position-top{{/if}}"
          id="smstab" disabled="{{noPhone}}"
          data-tooltip="{{#if noPhone}}In-app communication unavailable for Custom Ticket{{/if}}">
          SMS
          {{#unless noPhone}}<label class="counts">({{smscount}})</label>{{/unless}}
        </button>
      </div>
      {{/if}}
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button class="btn1 staff-btn {{unresolvedActive}}" id="staffnotestab">Notes
          <label class="counts">({{staffcount}})</label>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="show" style="display: none;">
    <div class="comments">
      {{> commentsList}}
    </div>
    <div class="comment-form">
      {{> commentSubmit}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="show2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="comments">
      {{> sendEmailList}}
    </div>
    {{#unless noEmail}}
    <div class="comment-form">
      {{> sendemail}}
    </div>
    {{/unless}}
  </div>
  <div id="show3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="comments">
      {{> sendSmsList}}
    </div>
    {{#unless noPhone}}
    <div class="comment-form">
      {{#if isPhoneNumberExists}}
      {{> sendsms}}
      {{/if}}
      {{> closesms}}
    </div>
    {{/unless}}
  </div>
  <div id="show4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="comments">
      <div class="panel panel-danger resolution-history"  style="border-color: #41E1EB;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background: #41e1eb; border-color: #41E1EB;">
          <p>Respond directly on the review site.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: none; border-color: #41E1EB;">
          <p>
            You can respond to this review using the link below. It will take you to the site's admin portal where you
            can post a reply.
          </p>
          {{#if oleryIframe}}
          <iframe src="{{oleryTabs.respond_url}}" style="width: 100%; height: 450px;"></iframe>
          {{else}}
          <a href="{{oleryTabs.respond_url}}" target="_blank">
            {{oleryTabs.respond_url}}
          </a>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<template name="analytics">
    <div class="panel panel-success analytics scrollbar ">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Statistics</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="">
            {{#if mobile}}
            <div id="statistics-dashboard" style="border: 1px solid white">
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary {{overallActive}} col-xs-3" id="overall" style="border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8px; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;">
                        {{#if smallMobile}}
                        <img src="/Overall_icon.png" style="height: 12px; width: 12px;">
                        {{else}}
                        <img src="/Overall_icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                        {{/if}}
                        Overall
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary {{teamActive}} col-xs-3" id="team" style="border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8px; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;">
                        {{#if smallMobile}}
                        <img src="/Team_icon.png" style="height: 12px; width: 12px;">
                        {{else}}
                        <img src="/Team_icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                        {{/if}}
                        Team
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary {{resolutionActive}} col-xs-3" id="resolution" style="border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8px; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;">
                        {{#if smallMobile}}
                        <img src="/Resolution_icon.png" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        {{else}}
                        <img src="/Resolution_icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                        {{/if}}
                        Resolve
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary {{shiftActive}} col-xs-3" id="shift" style="border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8px; padding: 10px 0; text-align: center;">
                        {{#if smallMobile}}
                        <img src="/Shifts_icon.png" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        {{else}}
                        <img src="/Shifts_icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                        {{/if}}
                        Shift
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            <div id="statistics-dashboard">
                <div class="btn-group  btn-group-justified">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary {{overallActive}} col-md-3 col-xs-12" id="overall"
                            style="width: 100%; padding-left: 5px; border: 1px solid white; border-left: none; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">
                            <img src="/Overall_icon.png" style="height:20px; width: 20px;">
                            Overall
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary {{teamActive}} col-md-3 col-xs-12" id="team"
                            style="width:90%; padding-left: 5px; border: 1px solid white; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">
                            <img src="/Team_icon.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                            Team
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary {{resolutionActive}} col-md-3 col-xs-12" id="resolution"
                            style="width: 125%; padding-left: 5px; margin-left: -10px; border: 1px solid white; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">
                            <img src="/Resolution_icon.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
                            Resolution
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary {{shiftActive}} col-md-3 col-xs-12" id="shift"
                            style="width: 90%; padding-left: 5px; margin-left: 10px; border: 1px solid white; border-right: none; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">
                            <img src="/Shifts_icon.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
                            Shift
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        {{#if overallActive}}
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="total-tickets">
                {{> totalTickets}}
            </div>
            <div id="active-staff">
                {{> activeStaff}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if resolutionActive}}
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="tickets-graph">
                {{> ticketsGraph}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if shiftActive}}
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{> shiftStatistics }}
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if teamActive}}
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="comment-stats">
                {{> commentStats}}
            </div>
            <div id="department-stats">
                {{> departmentStats}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help! Can add the JS files if necessary. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That depends on the templates you are rendering into these regions, and when they finish receiving the data they need before then can render. Can you post the templates you are rendering into these regions?

Comment: Hey Christian thanks for the response! The 3 templates are quite large and also have other templates in them so it might be too much to post. Could you explain the general idea behind how this works and maybe I'll be able to figure it out? Or any ideas you have to help? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: As @ChristianFritz suggested, you may be dependent on certain subscriptions that load first in analytics template so it gets rendered first. We can't tell for sure without a look at these templates so please share their code.

Comment: @HarryAdel I've updated the question with the template files, sorry that took a bit long. Would appreciate if you guys had any insight into this!

Comment: @ChristianFritz it wouldn't let me tag both of you in 1 comment but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You haven't not included the templates js files nor the publications/methods code.

Comment: The `yield` region is part of `ostrio:flow-router-extra` and it's async so first loaded = first rendered

Comment: @Jankapunkt thank you that's very helpful. I didn't know that beforehand as this is very legacy code but that makes a lot of sense. I'll play around with that part and see what we can do (maybe remove the yield entirely and just render the templates)